# PHPCS requires a license but my code is closed source

Tags: php, open-source, phpcs

After doing some digging online there doesn't seem to be an immediate answer to this.

I am writing code for a closed source application and when running PHPCS its informing me that an @license tag is required in order to conform to PSR standards.

I cannot apply an open source license to this code because the application is closed source proprietary code.

Does applying an @license tag with "No License" suffice to cover this requirement? Or is there a standard closed source license I should use?

Comment: What is the exact message  you receive? Anyway  it's really only a recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than applying a meaningless `@license` tag to every file, I'd instead recommend adjusting your config file to just ignore that particular sniff.

You can get the full name of the offending sniff with the `-s` command line option:

```
% vendor/bin/phpcs -s
------------------------------------------------------------------
  18 | ERROR   | Missing @license tag in class comment
     |         | (PEAR.Commenting.ClassComment.MissingLicenseTag)
```

Then add that to an `exclude` line in your `phpcs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyProject">
    <rule ref="PEAR">
        <exclude name="PEAR.Commenting.ClassComment.MissingLicenseTag"/>
    </rule>
    <file>src</file>
</ruleset>
```